# What version of MongoDB is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu

Hi I'm a bit of a shell n00b.

Can anyone tell me how I would check the version of MongoDB that is installed on my Linux Ubuntu machine?

I see that my MongoDB shell version: 1.2.2 so Im pretty sure that MongoDB itself is out dated too. And does anyone know of any 'How to update MongoDB' docs? I find mongodb.org to be a bit confusing.

Please and thank you.

---

Ok if I use db.version() inside of mongo shell it says 1.2.2

If I $ mongod --version I get this:

```
db version v1.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Oct 16 10:28:22 git version: nogitversion
```

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

and get

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 179 not upgraded.

mongod --version
db version v1.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Oct 16 10:31:07 git version: nogitversion
```

So why isn't it updating? Is apt-get pointing at the wrong repo / source?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/

Comment: In the mongo console, `db.version()` should tell you the version

Comment: Yes db.version() works great thank you!

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you? Are you using the 10gen lists?

Comment: Yes I was using the 10gen list I just missed the line where I set the version number that I want to install. See my edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ANSWER: Read the instructions #dua

Ok the magic was in this line that I apparently missed when installing was:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.4.6
```

And the full process as described here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ is

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
$ echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.3
$ echo "mongodb-10gen hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ sudo service mongodb start

$ mongod --version
db version v2.4.6
Wed Oct 16 12:21:39.938 git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure you change 2.4.6 to the latest version (or whatever you want to install). Find the latest version number here http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Answer (score 52):

inside shell:

```
$ mongod --version
```

Comment: But how do you get to the shell :/

Comment: @JamieHutber It's just the usual Ubuntu shell prompt on your linux machine. akluth's answer below may help you on how to start the shell prompt http://stackoverflow.com/a/19405892/154325
On Ubuntu, I like the handy shortcut CTRL + ALT + T

Answer (score 39):

To be complete, a short introduction for "shell noobs":

First of all, start your shell - you can find it inside the common desktop environments under the name "Terminal" or "Shell" somewhere in the desktops application menu.

You can also try using the key combo CTRL+F2, followed by one of those commands (depending on the desktop envrionment you're using) and the ENTER key:

```
xfce4-terminal
gnome-console
terminal
rxvt
konsole
```

If all of the above fail, try using `xterm` - it'll work in most cases.

Hint for the following commands: Execute the commands without the `$` - it's just a marker identifying that you're on the shell.

After that just fire up `mongod` with the `--version` flag:

```
$ mongod --version
```

It shows you then something like

```
$ mongod --version
db version v2.4.6
Wed Oct 16 16:17:00.241 git version: nogitversion
```

To update it just execute

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Comment: Being a console noob you must presume she does not know where ubuntu has installed mongod to

Comment: To be complete I've added a short introduction on how to spawn a shell for those "real" noobs :-P

Answer (score 13):

When you entered in mongo shell using "mongo" command , that time only you will notice

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0-rc2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0-rc2
```

also you can try command,in mongo shell ,
**`db.version()`**

Comment: sorry!!! downvoted by mistake and unable to revert it!!! please edit ur answer to upvote.

Comment: try now. And avoid such mistakes in future @shivadarshan

Answer (score 10):

In the terminal just enter the traditional command:

```
mongod --version
```

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal just write :
$ mongod --version